# Como adicionar dependências no build.sbt de modo que fiquem disponíveis nos módulos?

Tags: scala, sbt

Estou começando a utilizar SBT para projetos em scala e gostaria de criar um projeto como:

```
APP
...Module1
...Module2
    ...Module3

...
build.sbt
```

gostaria de saber como que aodciono dependências no build.sbt de modo que estas sejam utilizadas também nos módulos.

Agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir os módulos independentemente no build.sbt da seguinte forma:

```
lazy val module1 = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= deps
  )

lazy val module2 = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= deps
  )

lazy val module3 = (project in file("modules/module3"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= deps
  )

 val deps = List(
    "dependencia1" %% "exemplo" % "X.Y.Z",
    "dependencia2" %% "exemplo" % "X.Y.Z",
  )
```

No exemplo acima os módulos são definidos incluindo a lista de dependências. O modulo3 define explicitamente o caminho de onde o sbt busca o seu main `App`.

Outra forma é definir uma relação de dependência entre os módulos:

```
lazy val module2 = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= deps
  )

lazy val module3 = (project in file("modules/module3"))
  .settings()
  .dependsOn(module2)
```

Nesse caso não é necessário redefinir o valor `libraryDependencies` pro `module3`